# Convert column to string for concatenation

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
Date        ID      Date_ID
1990-12-31  96187   1990-12-31 00:00:00_906187.0
```

The column "Date_ID" is formed by concatenating the first two columns:

```
df['Date_ID'] = df['Date'].map(str)+"_"+ df['ID'].map(str)
```

The problem that I have is that the result of the concatenation is ending in ".0"...this means that it's not matching with other parts of my code.  I had thought that ".map(str)" would fix it but it does not. How can I get concatenation result to omit the ".0" from the column "ID"?

Thanks

Comment: your `ID` column might be of type `float`, so you get `.0` when converting to string.

Comment: How'd you get that ID column in the first place? Was it from reading some csv file? In that case might be easiest to fix the import operation to read in that column as a string to prevent the unnecessary converstion with an argument like `dtypes={'ID': 'str'}`.

Comment: Ensure that ID is an integer (or string) all the time. Otherwise larger numbers may be inexact which shouldn't happen for an ID.

Comment: The ID column comes from excel. In excel, it's a mix of number types and text. When it is imported, it's coming in as an 'object' datatype. When I try to convert it to .astype("str"), the column is still showing up as an object. Note I'm melting the import data first to generate my column "ID"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `.map(str)` consider controlling the format produced by your map conversion to match the rest of your code. For example, `.map(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` and/or `.map(lambda x: str(int(x)))` which could result in a snippet like:

```
df['Date_ID'] = df['Date'].map(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+"_"+ df['ID'].map(lambda x: str(int(x)))
```

**edit**
If you're not sure that x can be converted to an int, you might want to go ahead and control your id formatting even more comprehensively, e.g. with something like:

```
def format_id(x):
  if x is None:
    return "__your_choice__"
  elif math.isnan(x):
    return "__your_other_choice"
  elif isinstance(x, float):
    return f"{:.0f}"
  else:
    return

df['Date_ID'] = df['Date'].map(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+"_"+ df['ID'].map(format_id)
```

Note that in general if you can avoid this type of map / lambda you should, because this precludes pandas optimizations that would be available if you could, for example, use `.astype(str)`

Comment: Hi James.  Thanks for coming back to me. The ID column is dtype "Object". I tried your lamda method, and I got an error message saying "cannot convert float NaN to integer". Removing the int(x) part of the code gets me the same answer as before - ie the data ends ".0"